# Add tests for dependent :destroy in the Relationship model (Chapter 11, Exercise 1 Rails Tutorial, 2nd Ed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org, rails-console, dependent-destroy

Pretty sure these tests are working correctly. Got them to fail by removing the dependent: :destroy options on the has_many :relationships and has_many :reverse_relationships in user.rb.

Wanted to share what I did in case anyone else is working through [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition, Chapter 11 Exercises.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.2#sec:following_exercises)

A few questions arose from this exercise (see bottom of this post). If anyone could help, that'd be great.

**Chapter 11, Exercise 1:**

Add tests for dependent :destroy in the Relationship model (Listing 11.4 and Listing 11.16) by following the example in Listing 10.15.

Here's my test:
*spec/models/user_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  [...code omitted...]

  describe "relationship associations" do
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      @user.save
      @user.follow!(other_user)
      other_user.follow!(@user)
    end

    it "should destroy associated relationships" do
      relationships = @user.relationships
      @user.destroy
      relationships.should be_empty
    end

    it "should destroy associated reverse relationships" do
      reverse_relationships = @user.reverse_relationships
      @user.destroy
      reverse_relationships.should be_empty
    end
  end
```

---

A couple questions arose from this exercise:

**Question 1:**

My initial tests were
relationships.should be_nil
reverse_relationships.should be_nil

But, realized an array was still being returned, despite no user existing.
So, when a user doesn't exist and an association method is called, the result is still an array? Is this always true?

**Question 2:**

I wanted to play around with deleting relationships and reverse_relationships for a user in the rails console.

I tried this

```
> user = User.first
> user.relationships
 # returns a bunch of relationships
> user.relationships.destroy
=> []
> user.relationships
 # returns same bunch of relationships
```

How do I actually destroy the relationships permanently? Seems like good thing to know when exploring in console.

Thanks! I'm still pretty new to Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a ruby/rails noob too.

Question 1:
Searched [rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for `has_many` and it says

> Returns an array of all the associated objects. An empty array is returned if none are found.

On a side note, you can test for both nil and empty:

```
relationships.present?.should be_false
```

Question 2:
The `user.relationships.destroy` requires an :id

```
user.relationships.destroy '1'
```

Answer (score 4):

may be you need smt like this

```
it { should have_many(:relationships).dependent(:destroy) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your code with your question.  I only wanted to post this as a comment and not an answer, but it seems I can't yet.  Anyway, I just wanted to add a small potential candidate to your tests, but from the `other_user`'s perspective.  The test is similar to the follow/unfollow tests, so hopefully it'd not too redundant, but it tests `relationships` directly and not the `followed_users` and `followers` that go through them.

```
describe "relationship associations" do
  ...
  context "when a follower/followed user is destroyed" do
    subject { other_user }

    before { user.destroy }

    its(:relationships) { should_not include(user) }
    its(:reverse_relationships) { should_not include(user) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

**Exercise 11.5.1** Add tests for destroying relationships associated with a given user.

This code works for me. I've tried to follow the example [Listing 10.15](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-micropost_dependency_test).

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do 
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  describe "user relationships associations" do
    let (:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let (:another_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before do
      @user.save
      @user.follow!(other_user)
      @user.follow!(another_user)
      other_user.follow!(@user)
      other_user.follow!(another_user)
      another_user.follow!(@user)
      another_user.follow!(other_user)
    end

    its(:followed_users) { should include(other_user) }
    its(:followers) { should include(another_user) }

    it "should destroy associated followers" do
      followers = @user.followers
      @user.destroy
      followers.each do |follower|
        follower.followed_users.should_not include(@user)
      end
    end

    it "should destroy associated followed users" do
      followed_users = @user.followed_users
      @user.destroy
      followed_users.each do |followed_user|
        followed_user.followers.should_not include(@user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: paul, the relationships array is not constituted by users, so his include() should always be false, so the test always green.
Re: maria, it appears that the followed_users and followers methods won't return a user who doesn't exist, even when if a relationship referencing he or she remains.  So this test is never red also.

another solution:

```
  describe "relationships" do
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      @user.save
      @user.follow!(other_user)
    end

    let(:relationship) { @user.relationships.last }

    describe "should be destroyed when the followed user is destroyed" do
      before { other_user.destroy }
      its(:relationships) { should_not include(relationship) }
    end

    describe "should be destroyed when the following user is destroyed" do
      subject { other_user }
      before { @user.destroy }
      its(:reverse_relationships) { should_not include(relationship) }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work, but I figure I would share mine it's shorter.. :D

```
describe "following" do

  let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    @user.save
    @user.follow!(other_user)
    other_user.follow!(@user)
  end

   it { should be_following(other_user) }
   its(:followed_users) { should include(other_user) }

   it "should destroy associated followed_users and followers" do
     @user.destroy
     @user.relationships.present?.should be_false
     @user.reverse_relationships.present?.should be_false

     expect(other_user.followers).not_to include(@user)
     expect(other_user.followed_users).not_to include(@user)
   end
   .
   .
   .
   .
 end
end
```

P.S you can leave out:

```
@user.relationships.present?.should be_false
@user.reverse_relationships.present?.should be_false
```

but I throw it in there for someone who wants to make sure that all associated destroy action is at work.